ParsingException thrown when deleting rows from IXLTable
I was previously using version 0.101.0, and I'm currently testing version 0.104.1
The code works on version 0.101.0. It basically deletes extra rows on the table:
var lastRow = wbTable.DataRange.LastRow().RowNumber();
try
{
    if (lastRow > 1)
    {
        wbTable.DataRange.Rows(1, lastRow).Delete();
    }
}

Issuing the Delete command here produces this error
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      ClosedXML.Parser.ParsingException: Error at char 0 of '': Unexpected token EofSymbolId.
         at ClosedXML.Parser.FormulaParser`3.RefAtomExpression(Boolean replaceFirstAtom, TNode refAtom)
         at ClosedXML.Parser.FormulaParser`3.RefSpillExpression(Boolean replaceFirstAtom, TNode refAtom)
         at ClosedXML.Parser.FormulaParser`3.RefRangeExpression(Boolean replaceFirstAtom, TNode refAtom)
         at ClosedXML.Parser.FormulaParser`3.RefIntersectionExpression(Boolean replaceFirstAtom, TNode refAtom)
         at ClosedXML.Parser.FormulaParser`3.RefImplicitExpression(Boolean replaceFirstAtom, TNode refAtom)
         at ClosedXML.Parser.FormulaParser`3.RefExpression(Boolean replaceFirstAtom, TNode refAtom)
         at ClosedXML.Parser.FormulaParser`3.AtomExpression(Boolean skipRangeUnion, Boolean& isPureRef)
         at ClosedXML.Parser.FormulaParser`3.PrefixAtomExpression(Boolean skipRangeUnion, Boolean& isPureRef)
         at ClosedXML.Parser.FormulaParser`3.PercentExpression(Boolean skipRangeUnion, Boolean& isPureRef)
         at ClosedXML.Parser.FormulaParser`3.PowExpression(Boolean skipRangeUnion, Boolean& isPureRef)
         at ClosedXML.Parser.FormulaParser`3.MultiplyingExpression(Boolean skipRangeUnion, Boolean& isPureRef)
         at ClosedXML.Parser.FormulaParser`3.AdditiveExpression(Boolean skipRangeUnion, Boolean& isPureRef)
         at ClosedXML.Parser.FormulaParser`3.ConcatExpression(Boolean skipRangeUnion, Boolean& isPureRef)
         at ClosedXML.Parser.FormulaParser`3.Expression(Boolean skipRangeUnion, Boolean& isPureRef)
         at ClosedXML.Parser.FormulaParser`3.Formula()
         at ClosedXML.Parser.FormulaParser`3.CellFormulaA1(String formula, TContext context, IAstFactory`3 factory)
         at ClosedXML.Excel.CalcEngine.Visitors.FormulaReferences.ForFormula(String formula)
         at ClosedXML.Excel.XLDefinedName.set_RefersTo(String value)
         at ClosedXML.Excel.XLDefinedName.SetRefersTo(String formula)
         at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorksheet.MoveDefinedNamesRows(XLRange range, Int32 rowsShifted, XLDefinedNames definedNames)
         at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorksheet.<>c__DisplayClass293_0.<WorksheetRangeShiftedRows>b__0(XLWorksheet ws)
         at ClosedXML.Excel.EnumerableExtensions.ForEach[T](IEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 action)
         at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorksheet.WorksheetRangeShiftedRows(XLRange range, Int32 rowsShifted)
         at ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorksheet.NotifyRangeShiftedRows(XLRange range, Int32 rowsShifted)
         at ClosedXML.Excel.XLRangeBase.InsertRowsAboveInternal(Boolean onlyUsedCells, Int32 numberOfRows, Boolean formatFromAbove, Boolean nullReturn)
         at ClosedXML.Excel.XLRangeBase.InsertRowsBelowInternal(Boolean onlyUsedCells, Int32 numberOfRows, Boolean formatFromAbove, Boolean nullReturn)
         at ClosedXML.Excel.XLRangeBase.InsertRowsBelow(Boolean onlyUsedCells, Int32 numberOfRows, Boolean formatFromAbove)
         at ClosedXML.Excel.XLRangeBase.InsertRowsBelow(Int32 numberOfRows, Boolean expandRange)
         at ClosedXML.Excel.XLHelper.InsertRowsWithoutEvents(Func`3 insertFunc, XLTableRange tableRange, Int32 numberOfRows, Boolean expandTable)
         at ClosedXML.Excel.XLTableRange.InsertRowsBelow(Int32 numberOfRows)

Has anybody encountered the same error?

Your code worked in 0.101.0 and broke in 0.104.1. So, it could be a regression or breaking change in ClosedXML.
